# Why do I get iMessage notifications but not SMS notifications on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, sms

I have an iPhone 11 running iOS 17.1.1.

Whenever I get an SMS (say from 2FA login to a website or a friend using Android) my phone shows no notification... no buzz, no beep, the screen does not light up. However if I unlock the phone I see the notification as expected.

On the other hand if a friend also using iPhone messages (iMessage) me then these messages do generate notifications as expected.

I have looked in my Settings->Notifications->Messages settings but I cannot see any settings specific to iMessage/SMS. Why don't I get notifications and how can I fix this?

This is a clean restore on the phone from only a few weeks ago, I haven't changed any settings related to notifications, ringtones, etc from the defaults.